# Java8 Stream Conditional Handling

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of User objects.

```
public class User{
 private String name;
 private String role;
 private String status;
}
```

I wanted to use stream API to perform two operations.

1. See if list has User name as "Admin" if not throw custom exception (e.g UserNotFoundException)
2. If User name "Admin" is available in the list then mark the status of that user as "Active" and status of rest all users as "InActive".

How can i perform above operations in a concise way.

Comment: I think you can't do your task in single line stream. Do it in two steps. 1-  `if (users.stream().noneMatch(user -> user.getName().equals("Admin"))) throw new UserNotFound();` 2-`users.replaceAll(user->user.setStatus(user.getName().equals("Admin") ? "ACTIVE" : "INACTIVE");return user;});`

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet should do what you expect

```
List<User> userList = Arrays.asList(new User("Admin", null, "Draft"),
        new User("User", null, "Draft"));

userList.stream()
.filter(u -> u.name.equals("Admin"))
.peek(v -> userList.forEach(u -> u.status = u.name.equals("Admin") ? "Active" : "Inactive"))
.findAny()
.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);

userList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

In the `peek` function, I am streaming the `userList` once more to set the status. Even if we used a loop, to ensure correctness, we need to iterate twice. First to need to determine if `Admin` exist and again to set `status`.

**Output:**

```
User{name='Admin', status='Active'}
User{name='User', status='Inactive'}
```

Comment: This doesn’t work. After `filter(u -> u.name.equals("Admin"))`, only matching elements will be processed by the subsequent operations. So the `u.name.equals("Admin")`  check in the `peek` is pointless; it can only be true. Further, `findAny()` stops processing elements when a match has been found.

Comment: @Holger, in `peek` I am again calling `userList.forEach()`

Comment: Ok, I overlooked that, as I couldn’t imagine someone would really do that. It’s not making things better. And if no admin was found, it still didn’t process any element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps, 1. filter wi admin and throw an exception if does not match
2. Update the status

```
users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.name.equals("Admin"))
    .findAny().orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new).setStatus("Active");
users.stream()
    .filter(user -> !user.name.equals("Admin"))
    .forEach(user -> user.setStatus("Inactive"));
```